# Can I treat an 'unsigned long long' variable as an address to assign another variable?

Tags: c

I'm interested in whether an `unsigned long long` variable can be treated as an address, and the result seemed it was correct?

```
int var = 0;
// the variable var's address is 0x7fffffffe4a4 now in my system
unsigned long long ull = 0x7fffffffe4a4;
scanf("%d", ull);  // I try to use ull as var's address and assign a value to var
printf("%d\n", var);  // It seemingly works!
```

And I also conducted an experiment as follows.

```
int var = 0;
// the variable var's address is 0x7fffffffe4a4 now in my system
unsigned long long ull = 0x7fffffffe4a4;  
int *ptr = &var;

// First, I want to know whether the memory used by unsigned long long and the one used by a pointer differ
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ull));  
printf("%zu\n", sizeof(ptr));
// The results are both "8" in my system
// Next I try to assign two different values to var by two ways
scanf("%d", ull);  // I try to use x as an address to assign var
printf("%d\n", var);
scanf("%d", ptr);  // And I also use a normal pointer to assign var
printf("%d\n", var);
// The results were in line with expectations!
```

Well, it seems an `unsigned long long` variable can be used as a pointer successfully (although the compiler warned me that the argument was expected to be `int*` rather than `unsigned long long`), and I wonder …

What's the difference between a variable and a pointer at the hardware level? How are these two types of objects processed when they are stored and used? Who processes these objects and is it recommended to perform the operations above?

(In the end is it a feature of c?)

Comment: A pointer points to things, i.e. it stores an address.  A `unsigned long long` is an integer type, and it stores integer numbers.

Comment: There is no such language as C/C++. C and C++ are distinct languages.

Comment: What's the difference between an arrow and a target? :-)

Comment: First of all note there there's no such single language as "C/C++". C and C++ are two *very* different languages, and even for things that might seem simple like this one, there might be details that could lead to vastly different behavior.

Comment: On another note, mismatching `scanf` or `printf` format specifier and argument type leads to *undefined behavior*. In both languages. So e.g. `scanf("%d", ull)` is *never* correct.

Comment: With all this said, if you for some peculiar reason needs to store a pointer in an integer type, there's `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t`. Never use them directly when a pointer is needed though, always cast to the correct pointer type (and beware of strict aliasing problems).

Comment: `// The results are both "8" in my system` - and there are plenty of systems where that will not be the case. So what will you do if that happens?

Comment: We should start to rewrite our sources to use less pointers. _unsigned long long_ even rimes. Wasn't there a song with "long long"? Only C can do that!

Comment: Grab an `std::string` and **old** GCC compiler. Pass `std::string` to a format specifier expecting `char*`. Be surprised. Ask a question "what is the difeerence between `std::string` and `char*`".

Comment: The code is relying on *undefined behavior* doing what you expect. Don't expect it to behave like you expect on other systems. Rather than replacing a pointer value with an `unsigned long long` value in the function calls, it would be slightly better (but still undefined behavior) to replace it with a `uintptr_t`.

Comment: Entering an unsigned long long should be: `scanf("%llu", &ull);`

Comment: The only integer type with formal guarantees to be able to represent a pointer is `uintptr_t`. In practice, it's very likely the same size as `unsigned long long` on x86 systems though. Though on a 16 bit CPU `uintptr_t` might be 16 bits but `unsigned long long` 64 bits (needlessly big).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On many (most) platforms, pointers and (unsigned) integers are stored in very similar formats at the hardware level (on your system, both an `int*` pointer and an `unsigned long long` are 8 bytes). However, from the point of view of the C language and compiler, they are very different types of variable.

One notable difference in their behaviour concerns arithmetic. For integral types, arithmetic operations like `x = x + 1` do exactly what you would naturally expect. However, for pointers, such operations are performed in base units of the size of the pointed-to type.

The following code demonstrates this (on a platform with 8-byte pointers and `long long` and a 4-byte `int`):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int myInt = 42;
    int* ptr = &myInt;
    unsigned long long ull = (unsigned long long)ptr;
    printf("%p %016llX\n", (void*)ptr, ull);
    ++ptr;
    ++ull;
    printf("%p %016llX\n", (void*)ptr, ull);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
0000005B8A4FFC10 0000005B8A4FFC10
0000005B8A4FFC14 0000005B8A4FFC11
```

For the first line (as you have already noted), the two values are identical, and their binary representations will also be the same (on this platform). However, notice that the `++` increment behaves differently on the two types, so that the second line of output shows that the pointer has been incremented by `4` (the size of an `int`) but the unsinged integer has been incremented by `1`.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a good analogy: using numbers instead of pointers is not *wrong*, it's **dangerous**. Imagine at the reason why you don't use a bicycle on a highway. Is it because you **can't** ride it? Of course you can, you have wheels, the asphalt is good. You don't do it because it's dangerous, the bicycle is not designed to do it.

For a more formal explanation:

Congratulations, you discovered that addresses are, ultimately, just numbers. The reason why in languages such as C or C++ (they are different!!) pointers are introduced is to avoid confusion and errors, letting the users **and the compiler** know specifically when they are dealing with an address or a number.

As I said at the beginning, at the end of the day, an address is a number that needs to tell the hardware *where* to look in the memory. However a pointer is a number that is treated with special care by the compiler:

- You have the guarantee that a pointer has enough bits to store the address. Your example works "fine" with 64bits systems, but in a 16bits system a pointer will have the same range as a `unsigned short` value, and if you try to assign a `unsigned long` you will run into all sorts of problems.
- Arithmetic on pointers follow the size of the underlying pointed data type. When you are pointing at a `short` at address `0x100` and you want to go to the next byte, you know that you have to look at '0x102'.

```
short* ps = (short*)0x100;
ps += 1; // ps is now 0x102, because the compiler knows that short is 2 bytes
*ps = 0xAABB;

short s = 0x100;
// I need to advance to the next short.. mmm I have to do this:
s += sizeof(short). 
*((short*)s) = 0xAABB; // Also, ugly syntax. 

// See how easy it is to make errors when you use plain numbers?
```

Bottom line: pointers are special numbers with special properties, especially thought to handle memory accesses and address arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

They have the same size on certain platforms, and can then be typecast into the other without disregarding any number of bits. There is the `size_t` type, which represents the "return" type of `sizeof` and the is used to store size used in memory(in bytes) for a variable. `size_t` can be only 2 bytes big(`sizeof(size_t)`=`2`) on some platforms, but `long long`(whose `sizeof` is the same as the `sizeof` of `unsigned long long`) is always 8 or higher. It makes sense for pointers to any type to have the same `sizeof`. The number of bytes in the memory before the first byte referred to by the pointer is stored in the pointer, so it makes sense that its `sizeof` should be same as `sizeof` of a pointer to any type. So, I'd recommend using `size_t` if you want to store an address in an integral type.

Answer (score 1):

There are two fundamental issues here:

1. *Interpretation matters.*  In almost any programming language, the values we work with are not just raw bit patterns, they are bit patterns *interpreted as a particular type*.  For example, consider the binary number `0b111111101000000000000000000000`, or in hexadecimal, `0x3fa00000`.  Interpreted as an `int`, that's the number 1067450368.  Interpreted as a `float`, it's 1.25.  Same bit pattern, two completely different, totally unrelated numbers.  You could take the same bit pattern and try to interpret it as a pointer, but that would be a third, completely unrelated interpretation, and it wouldn't necessarily mean anything, either.
2. Just because you have a pointer value, pointing at (or containing) a certain memory address, doesn't necessarily mean you can actually *access* that memory.  It might be in use by some other variable in your program.  It might be in use by the actual code of your program.  It might be in use by some other program.  Or it might not exist at all — it might refer to a memory address that's higher than the total amount of memory in your computer.

So taking an integer value, converting it to a pointer, and then accessing the resulting memory is sort of like chipping golf balls off the top of a tall building: you have no idea where the balls are going to land, and they might hurt someone, and it's therefore a pretty irresponsible practice.